# JavaMail - Send plain HTML content without formatting

Tags: html, jakarta-mail, mime-types, content-type

I want to send an email using JavaMail with HTML tags not formatted.

I use this code :

```
public void sendMail() throws MessagingException, IllegalStateException, IllegalArgumentException {

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    messageBodyPart.setContent("<h1>This is an HTML message</h1>", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    message.setContent(multipart);

    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("noreply@localhost.com"));

    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("to@localhost.com"));

    message.setSubject("HTML mail");

    Transport.send(message);
}
```

I receive the email with formatted HTML :

> ## This is an HTML message

But I want html plain text :

> < h1>This is an HTML message< /h1>

Thanks for help !

Comment: What you have should work.  Possibly your mail reader is guessing that you really meant text/html even though you said text/plain because the text looks like html text?

Answer (score 0):

Use `message.setText()` instead of `message.setContent()`

Comment: This should have been a comment but you have not enough reputation for this.